# what process is calling `watchexec` in monterey (macos 12.1)?

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-monterey, console.app

After a routine reboot of Monterey (macOS 12.1) without having performed any software updates, I was asked to approve access for `watchexec` to various system locations such as `~/Documents` and `~/Desktop` but also my photos library, reminders and contacts. I checked console.app to see if I could determine what process was invoking `watchexec` but I couldn't find anything. Since I haven't seen this before and haven't been asked about this before, I am curious what this could be.

I have a suspicion that `watchexec` would have been installed as a dependency of something that I might've installed through `homebrew`, but I am not certain and I am not sure how to find that out--and if that is the case, I am not sure why it would've needed access to the locations to which it requested access. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/watchexec/watchexec

Comment: That is not helpful and I know how to find the source for `watchexec` myself. The question was how to find what the parent process is that is calling `watchexec`, which the github page does not address.